# Enable WebView pinch and zoom in android xamarin forms

Tags: webview, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I use web view in xamarin forms (ios-android) and IOS recognize pinch and zoom but in android nothing happened . How can I add this and for android ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I create custom renderer for WebView. I add following code inside OnElementPropertyChanged event.

**Android**

```
if(Control != null)
{
       Control.Settings.BuiltInZoomControls = true;
       Control.Settings.DisplayZoomControls = true;
}
```

Comment: And for iOS: Control.ScalesPageToFit = true;

Comment: For **Xamarin Mono Android**

            webView = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webView);
            webView.Settings.BuiltInZoomControls = true;